# Определение и блокировка бота в Apache

Tags: веб-программирование, apache, веб-сервер, бот, веб-сайт

Около месяца назад начал ломится какой-то бот на сайт.
Запросы идут с разных IP адресов.

ОС всегда Mac.

Страна, в основном United States, но бывают и другие.

В логах отображается примерно вот так:

> 45.128.145.214 - - [27/Nov/2021:00:49:44 +0200] "GET /agape/ HTTP/1.1" 200 17992 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1)
> AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115
> Safari/537.36"
> 45.133.236.9 - - [27/Nov/2021:00:49:47 +0200] "GET /map/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16096 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1)
> AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115
> Safari/537.36"
> 43.249.10.201 - - [27/Nov/2021:00:49:47 +0200] "GET /business/ HTTP/1.1" 200 20758 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X
> 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115
> Safari/537.36"
> 185.224.146.229 - - [27/Nov/2021:00:49:47 +0200] "GET /hangman/ HTTP/1.1" 200 19116 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X
> 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115
> Safari/537.36"
> 154.210.5.153 - - [27/Nov/2021:00:49:50 +0200] "GET /gallery/ HTTP/1.1" 200 17175 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X
> 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115
> Safari/537.36"

Возможно как-то определить кто это и заблокировать его?

Comment: Но стоит отметить побочку решения через бан user-agent в .htaccess - все реальные пользователи, попадающие под эту регулярку тоже не смогу зайти)

Comment: Актуальная версия юзергаента для хрома Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36, так что маловероятно, что бан будет реальным пользователям

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заблокировать через .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
  SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent ".*Chrome\/59.0.3071.115 Safari\/537.36*" block
<Limit GET>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    Deny from env=block
</Limit>
</IfModule>
```

.*Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36* - регулярка для определения нужного юзерагента